# Apply Document Height to a div using Jquery

Tags: height, document

Merry Xmas,

I have an issue in applying div height using jquery.

I need to have the (.leftstatbar) div to be of the height of the entire document. But thats not happening with this. There is a white space at the bottom, as the other document exceeds the height of this div.

Here is what I have tried

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function (){
  var winWidth = $ (window).innerWidth();
  var winHeight = $ (document).innerHeight();
  // set initial div height / width

  $('.leftstatbar').css({
    'width': '250px',
    'height': winHeight
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    var winWidth1 = $ (window).innerWidth();
     var winHeight1 = $ (document).innerHeight();

     $('.leftstatbar').css({
    'width': '250px',
    'height':winHeight1
  });
});
});
```

My issue is , With the above code I am unable to get the initial height. My document is lengthier than the div (.leftstatbar). Another problem is with the resizer. It resizes initially but then it wont.

Kindly support

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The methods innerHeight() and innerWidth() do not apply to the window or document objects.  You should use height() and width() instead.  See here: http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/

The issue with your resizer is that you are doing a closure on the initial values from the calls to innerHeight() and innerWidth() and then setting the size of DIV to the same value over and over as the resizer is called.  You should set the value of the height to the height of the document at the time the function is called (dynamically).

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.leftstatbar').css({
    'width': '250px',
    'height':$(document).css("height");
    });
});
```

Use .css("height") instead of height() in this case to automatically include the units (px).